# Sentry Breadcrumb on aws Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sentry

When the AWS Lambda function is freezed and restarted (hot start) the previous breadcrumb messages are still there and on the Sentry dashboard we see the old messages.

Seems the breadcrumb is not cleared after the captureException call. Which is the right way to clear the context between call even when the function is reused?

```
Sentry.init({
    dsn: process.env.dsn,
    environment: process.env.environment,
    release: process.env.release
});
try {
    Sentry.configureScope(scope => {
       scope.setTag('transaction', context.awsRequestId);
       scope.setTag('lambda', context.functionName);
    });

    Sentry.addBreadcrumb({
        category: 'store',
        message: 'Test',
        level: Sentry.Severity.Info
    });
    throw new Error('Something bad happened');
} catch (error) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    Sentry.captureException(error);
    await Sentry.flush(context.getRemainingTimeInMillis());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the sparse documentation on this, but doing right after `init`:

```
Sentry.configureScope(scope => {
   scope.clear();
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I was browsing through Sentry's documentation and I found this page: https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/scopes/?platform=javascript

Maybe you folks could add an example on how to clear the Scope there? It's very implicit right now as one needs to go through the whole page in order to see it.

Thanks!